# AWS Python Lambda Function - Write a UTF-8 encoded CSV to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a CSV file to my S3 bucket from inside a Lambda function. Everything is fine, except I cannot capture special characters; basically I need my file to be UTF-8 encoded. I do not want to use pandas or unicodecsv as those are not inbuilt to Lambda's environment.

Below is my current Lambda function:

```
import boto3
import csv
import io

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket("my-bucket-name-goes-here")
    fn = "sample_csv_lambda.csv"
    write_csv(fn, bucket)

def write_csv(target_filename, bucket):
    buff = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buff, dialect="excel", delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow([f"header{i}" for i in range(1, 6)])
    writer.writerow([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    writer.writerow(["u", "b", "w", "d", "ş"])
    writer.writerow(["n", "p", "m", "q", "ğ"])
    buff2 = io.BytesIO(buff.getvalue().encode(encoding="UTF-8"))
    print(buff2.getvalue().decode("utf-8"))
    bucket.upload_fileobj(buff2, target_filename)
```

The print value on the second-to-last line outputs the special characters as intended, however once I download and open the CSV file, the characters in it are still not UTF-8.

PS: I like the current formulation of my code as I do not need to temporarily save the file in a "/tmp" folder as suggested by some other questions/answers. I also do not need to package and upload pandas/unicodecsv to my Lambda environment; too complicated for a beginner like me. Please keep this in mind when you answer.

Comment: Python3 strings are UTF8 already. What does `are still not UTF-8.` mean? Is the text mangled? Did you expect non-English characters to somehow change? This page is UTF8, the code you posted is UTF8, `"ğ"` is a UTF8 string with a single character

Comment: The csv file that is created and downloaded has 5 columns and 5 rows. The values ofş and ğ are appearing as ÅŸ and ÄŸ. I believe the resulting csv is not UTF-8

Comment: No, that's **exactly** what UTF8 looks like when you open it as if it was Latin1. What OS are. you using? What. locale. settings?Which program do you use to read the file?

Comment: What am I doing wrong? I am used to saving CSVs as "utf-8-sig" encoded when I work with pandas. What encoding should I be using here if I want the end result to include the characters as I want them to be?

Comment: You just proved that the file really is UTF8. UTF8 encodes characters above the first 127 as two or more bytes, using very specific values for the first byte. Guess what that byte looks like in Latin1 ..

Comment: *You're doing nothing wrong in your code*. Where and how are you loading that UTF8 file?

Comment: BTW I am using Windows and opening the CSV with Excel as I wrote on the other answer, you might have missed that.

Comment: Why is this so complicated to package unicode csv? In the worst case just copy the code from there to your lambda

Comment: I am very new to Lambda and have no packaging/zipping/uploading experience. I would prefer to use the inbuilt modules for now.

Comment: Put the relevant information in the *question*, not comments.I bet you double clicked on the file instead of importing it too. When you do that, Excel *imports the file's contents* using defaults. The default for non-UTF16 text is to use the user's locale. `saving CSVs as "utf-8-sig" ` but here you used `utf-8` which doesn't emit the BOM that would tell Excel this is a UTF8 file

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lambda or even Python - except for using `utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8`. If you want to create Excel files, you can use a library like opepyxl to create real Excel files. What you do now is force Excel to *import* a text file using defaults. If you used the Data > Import menu you'd be able to specify the encoding. Right now Excel has to guess

Comment: Changing the encoding from "utf-8" to "utf-8-sig" has fixed the issue. I didn't realize that was an acceptable value for the argument, I thought it was specific to pandas.

Comment: No, that's discussed in the [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) documentation

Comment: Should I remove the question or is it relevant for future use?

Comment: And thank you @PanagiotisKanavos for the clarification and the solution, maybe you want to add it as an answer for me to mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

The file is already UTF8, without a BOM. To emit a BOM, use `utf-8-sig` instead of `utf-8` when encoding.

**Long Answer**

From the comments, it looks like you're trying to open a CSV file in Excel by double-clicking on the file. When you do that Excel will *import* the file contents using default settings. If a BOM is present, Excel will load the file using the encoding specified by the BOM. Without it there's no way to guess what encoding was used, so Excel will use the user's locale settings to import the data.

If you used the Data menu to import the data, Excel would show you a preview of the file and allow you to modify settings like the encoding, delimiters etc.

If you want to use that file with Excel, it would be a good idea to use a library like `openpyxl` to create a real `xlsx` file. An `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing well-define XML files. An `xlsx` file is typically a lot smaller than the equivalent CSV file and has no localization issues with numbers and dates.